OpenTelemetry Web: instrumentation package for exceptions
Consider a web page (pure front-end, html/js/css), i want to configure opentelemetry to automatically get all the console logs (in particular exceptions) and send all the data to otel collector.
Is it possibile?
Can someone provide an example?
At the moment I’ve only tested this sample:
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js/tree/main/examples/opentelemetry-web
It’s ok but seems to not have an instrumentation package to grab console logs.
